# Error when installing watchman on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10

i'm trying to install watchman (for using it with react native) on ubuntu 18.10 but when i do the "make" command it gives me an error. This is the log:

```
aupetrone@aupetrone-X580VD:~/watchman$ ./autogen.sh
aupetrone@aupetrone-X580VD:~/watchman$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for inline... inline
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for FOLLY... no
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for pcre-config... false
checking for PCRE using false... failed
checking for library containing pthread_create... -lpthread
checking for library containing socket... none required
checking for library containing SHA1_Init... -lcrypto
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking port.h usability... no
checking port.h presence... no
checking for port.h... no
checking sys/inotify.h usability... yes
checking sys/inotify.h presence... yes
checking for sys/inotify.h... yes
checking sys/event.h usability... no
checking sys/event.h presence... no
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking sys/ucred.h usability... no
checking sys/ucred.h presence... no
checking for sys/ucred.h... no
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for mkostemp... yes
checking for kqueue... no
checking for port_create... no
checking for inotify_init... yes
checking for strtoll... yes
checking for localeconv... yes
checking for statfs... yes
checking for accept4... yes
checking for inotify_init1... yes
checking for getattrlistbulk... no
checking for openat... yes
checking for fdopendir... yes
checking for pipe2... yes
checking for sys/vfs.h... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for sys/mount.h... yes
checking for sys/statfs.h... yes
checking for sys/statvfs.h... yes
checking valgrind/valgrind.h usability... no
checking valgrind/valgrind.h presence... no
checking for valgrind/valgrind.h... no
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking sys/resource.h usability... yes
checking sys/resource.h presence... yes
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
checking CoreServices/CoreServices.h usability... no
checking CoreServices/CoreServices.h presence... no
checking for CoreServices/CoreServices.h... no
checking for FSEventStreamSetExclusionPaths... no
checking for backtrace... yes
checking for backtrace_symbols... yes
checking for backtrace_symbols_fd... yes
checking for sys_siglist... yes
checking for memmem... yes
checking for struct statvfs.f_fstypename... no
checking for struct statvfs.f_basetype... no
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating thirdparty/jansson/jansson_config.h
config.status: creating cppclient/watchmanclient.pc
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

Your build configuration:

        CC = gcc
        CPPFLAGS =  -D_REENTRANT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
        CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -g -gdwarf-2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
        CXX = g++
        CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -g -gdwarf-2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
        LDFLAGS = 
        prefix: /usr/local
        version: 4.9.0
        state directory: /usr/local/var/run/watchman

aupetrone@aupetrone-X580VD:~/watchman$ make
make  all-am
make[1]: ingresso nella directory "/home/aupetrone/watchman"
  CXX      watchman-ChildProcess.o
  CXX      watchman-ContentHash.o
  CXX      watchman-CookieSync.o
  CXX      watchman-FileDescriptor.o
  CXX      watchman-FileInformation.o
  CXX      watchman-InMemoryView.o
  CXX      watchman-Pipe.o
  CXX      watchman-PubSub.o
  CXX      watchman-ThreadPool.o
  CXX      watchman-QueryableView.o
  CXX      watchman-spawn.o
  CXX      watchman-opt.o
  CXX      watchman-cfg.o
  CXX      watchman-clockspec.o
  CXX      watchman-checksock.o
  CXX      watchman-error_category.o
  CXX      watchman-fstype.o
  CXX      watchman-log.o
  CXX      watchman-ignore.o
  CXX      watchman-json.o
  CXX      watchman-bser.o
  CXX      watchman-expflags.o
  CXX      watchman-hash.o
  CXX      watchman-ioprio.o
  CXX      watchman-opendir.o
  CXX      watchman-pending.o
  CXX      watchman-perf.o
  CXX      watchman-stream.o
  CXX      watchman-stream_stdout.o
  CXX      watchman-stream_unix.o
  CXX      watchman-timedlock.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-find.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-info.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-log.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-query.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-since.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-reg.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-state.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-subscribe.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-trigger.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-watch.o
  CXX      cmds/watchman-debug.o
  CXX      query/watchman-base.o
  CXX      query/watchman-dirname.o
  CXX      query/watchman-parse.o
  CXX      query/watchman-eval.o
  CXX      query/watchman-glob.o
  CXX      query/watchman-intcompare.o
  CXX      query/watchman-type.o
  CXX      query/watchman-suffix.o
  CXX      query/watchman-match.o
  CXX      query/watchman-pcre.o
  CXX      query/watchman-name.o
  CXX      query/watchman-fieldlist.o
  CXX      query/watchman-since.o
  CXX      query/watchman-empty.o
  CXX      watcher/watchman-auto.o
  CXX      watcher/watchman-fsevents.o
  CXX      watcher/watchman-inotify.o
  CXX      watcher/watchman-kqueue.o
  CXX      watchman-launchd.o
  CXX      watchman-listener.o
  CXX      watchman-listener-user.o
  CXX      watchman-clientmode.o
  CXX      watchman-main.o
  CXX      root/watchman-ageout.o
  CXX      root/watchman-crawler.o
  CXX      root/watchman-dir.o
  CXX      root/watchman-file.o
  CXX      root/watchman-init.o
  CXX      root/watchman-iothread.o
  CXX      root/watchman-notifythread.o
  CXX      root/watchman-poison.o
  CXX      root/watchman-reap.o
  CXX      root/watchman-resolve.o
  CXX      root/watchman-stat.o
  CXX      root/watchman-symlink.o
  CXX      root/watchman-sync.o
  CXX      root/watchman-threading.o
  CXX      root/watchman-vcs.o
  CXX      root/watchman-warnerr.o
  CXX      root/watchman-watchlist.o
  CXX      scm/watchman-Mercurial.o
scm/Mercurial.cpp: In constructor ‘watchman::Mercurial::infoCache::infoCache(std::__cxx11::string)’:
scm/Mercurial.cpp:16:40: error: ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ clearing an object of non-trivial type ‘struct watchman::FileInformation’; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Werror=class-memaccess]
   memset(&dirstate, 0, sizeof(dirstate));
                                        ^
In file included from scm/Mercurial.h:10,
                 from scm/Mercurial.cpp:3:
./FileInformation.h:18:8: note: ‘struct watchman::FileInformation’ declared here
 struct FileInformation {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4446: scm/watchman-Mercurial.o] Error 1
make[1]: uscita dalla directory "/home/aupetrone/watchman"
make: *** [Makefile:1264: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Running `./configure --without-python  --without-pcre --enable-lenient` before `make` will do the trick.

Comment: This fixes the issue on 19.04 as well, thanks

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you explain how does this fix it?

Comment: also fixes the issue on vanilla debian 10 buster, thanks!

Comment: Helps with 20.04 too, thanks.