# How install watchman on Ubuntu 19.10 for react native

Tags: android-studio, 19.10, visual-studio-code, watch-command

I was try to installing watchman on Ubuntu 19.10 but it throwing some issues.

My commands:

$ cd ~

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git

$ cd watchman/

$ git checkout v4.9.0

$ sudo apt-get install -y autoconf automake build-essential
python-dev

$ ./autogen.sh 

$ ./configure 

$ make

$ sudo make install$ watchman --version
```

Issues:

```
    scm/Mercurial.cpp: In constructor ‘watchman::Mercurial::infoCache::infoCache(std::string)’:
scm/Mercurial.cpp:16:40: error: ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ clearing an object of non-trivial type ‘struct watchman::FileInformation’; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Werror=class-memaccess]
   16 |   memset(&dirstate, 0, sizeof(dirstate));
      |                                        ^
In file included from scm/Mercurial.h:10,
                 from scm/Mercurial.cpp:3:
./FileInformation.h:18:8: note: ‘struct watchman::FileInformation’ declared here
   18 | struct FileInformation {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4446: scm/watchman-Mercurial.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/elavarasan/watchman-4.9.0'
make: *** [Makefile:1264: all] Error 2
```

Expecting:
 the watchman install successfully. 
 watchman version 4.9.0

Answer (score 3):

Running

```
./configure --without-python --without-pcre --enable-lenient
```

before `make` will do the trick.
I found the answer [in this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088137/error-when-installing-watchman-on-ubuntu-18-10).